# celery: remove empty queues that are more than 5 minutes old?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I am trying to clean up all the stale queues that linger. I want to remove queues that have been empty for over 5 minutes.

another way I was thinking of is using pyrabbit to access the queue directly but not sure how I can find out if a queue is older than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this from command line using

```
sudo rabbitmqctl set_policy expiry ".*" '{"expires":300000}' --apply-to queues
```

This deletes all unused queues after 300 seconds. Unused means the queue has no consumers, the queue has not been redeclared, and has not been invoked for a duration of at least the expiration period.

Note this expiry time can also be set when declaring a queue. More at [rabbitmq docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html).

Comment: In case if you want to clear expiry you can run  `sudo rabbitmqctl clear_policy expiry` to remove it.